# TextRange.Find().Delete method is deleting leading/trailing spaces in a textbox

Tags: vba, powerpoint, textrange

The text in the shape "TextBox 1" is "Work stack.<8Spaces>###Resource: Name1".
I want to delete "###" from the above text using ppt vba. The text in the shape after the below statement gets executed is "Work stack. Resource: Name1".

```
MyPPT.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Find("###").Delete
```

It's deleting the spaces after the period but I want to keep those spaces i.e. the desired output is "Work stack.<8Spaces>Resource: Name1". Replace(FindWhat:="###", ReplaceWhat:=vbNullString) works really well but I wanted to check whether this is the default behavior of delete method or is it misbehaving or is there a way to change this behavior through ppt textbox properties or some other settings. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @BigBen It's just a plain text box added manually to a powerpoint slide.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the intended behavior of `Delete`. When done manually the behavior is similar, i.e. if `###` is selected in the textbox, <kbd>←Backspace</kbd> clears the leading white space. The behavior of `Cut` is similar.

Maybe use `Replace` with a blank string instead of `Delete`.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim MyPPT As Presentation
    Set MyPPT = ActivePresentation

    MyPPT.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Replace FindWhat:="###", ReplaceWhat:=""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you time but my sincere apologies for not rephrasing my question. I wanted to check whether "delete" method is misbehaving and if yes is there a workaround using "delete" method itself. I've used replace using vbNullString already which works really well. I'm really sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's unintended. `Delete` behaves similarly to Backspace, if the `###` is selected first manually. `Cut` does the same thing (as seen also with Ctrl + X).